# Cannot Implicitly convert type "System.Collection.Generic.List<T>" to "T"

Tags: api, xamarin

I have API method like as following to get data from server

```
        public static async Task<T> GetResultsFromApiUsingPost<T>(string serviceUrl)
            {
                     //some code
                     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var responseJson = stringAsync;
                            var content= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(responseJson);
                            return content;//here getting error
                        }`
```

I need to return `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(responseJson);`,how to resolve this.

Comment: can you change return type to  Task<List<T>>

Comment: ya, your `content` is a `List` data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function Says Return T but your actually return List T

```
public static async Task<List<T>> GetResultsFromApiUsingPost<T>(string serviceUrl)
{
//some code
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
       var responseJson = stringAsync;
       var content= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(responseJson);
       return content;//here getting error
 }`
```